# Finding the expression of a function $C^{1}([0,l])$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Consider $ 0 < \beta < \alpha < l < \infty $ and $f \in C^{1}([0,l])$ such that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ forall $x \in [0,l]$. Also, consider that $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in [0,\beta]$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in [\alpha,l]$.

As in the figure.
[image]

I would like to know the expression of the function in the range of $(\beta, \alpha)$. I think that
$$
f(x) = ax^{3} + bx^{2} + cx + \delta, \quad x \in [\beta, \alpha]
$$
where $1 = f(\beta) = a\beta^{3} + b\beta^{2} + c\beta + \delta$ and $0 = f(\alpha) = a\alpha^{3} + b \alpha^{2} + c \alpha + \delta $.

But I can't solve such a system and I don't know if that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: There are many such function, but if you want to use a polynomial, certainly you can. And I think you are the right track, just try harder. You should have four equations, not only two. (Because two endpoints and you care for value and value of the derivative). When solving the system, mind that $\alpha$, $\beta$ are just fixed numbers.

Comment: @minorChaos But do I know what the derivative of the function ($f^{\prime}(x) = 3ax^{2} + 2bx + c$) is worth at some point?

Comment: @minorChaos I have $f^{\prime}(\beta) =f^{\prime}(\alpha) = f^{\prime}(0) = 0$, right?

Comment: What is  x^2 + 3 worth at some point (say 0 or 1 or 7) ? What is  $\sin x$ worth  at $\pi/2$?

Comment: if $f$ is the polynomial, you indeed wish to have $f' (\beta) =0$. Correct. You will not say about $f'(\alpha)$. But I will express my doubts about $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: I arrived $\delta = 1$, $a = \dfrac{1}{\alpha^{2}(\beta - \alpha)}$, $b = -\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha^{2}(\beta - \alpha)}$ and $c = 0$.

Comment: c=0, hmm, that sounds like you went for $f'(0)=0$, hmm, I again express my doubts

Comment: Warning: in the comments you use $f$ for the polynomial, in the question you use $f$ for the $C^1$ function from the picture. This collision bring misunderstanding.

Comment: @minorChaos My main goal would be to plot this figure in some program: geogebra or otherwise. But for that I need to know the expression of my function in $(\beta, \alpha)$. Here $\beta$ and $\alpha$ would be any point in $(0,l)$.

Comment: @minorChaos But in fact, with these values I am arriving with a curve above one, see https://www.geogebra.org/calculator   here $\beta = 1/2 $ and $\alpha = 3/2$

Comment: wrong link - to empty geogebra

Comment: @minorChaos For those values I mentioned above I get

$f(x) = \dfrac{x^{3}}{\alpha^{2}(\beta - \alpha)} - \dfrac{\beta x^{2}}{\alpha^{2}(\beta - \alpha)} +1$ https://www.geogebra.org/calculator

Comment: How does the picture looks for =1 and =7 ?

Comment: @minorChaos So it's almost the line$ y = 1$ because $\alpha^{2} (\beta - \alpha = 294$

Comment: It should be $0$ at $7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any information you could get from the function being differentiable everywhere in [0,l], for example at the borders between it being straight and a curve? This might give you enough equations to solve the system.

Hint: $\frac d{dx}(x^3)=3x^2$

Comment: I have $f^{\prime}(\beta) =f^{\prime}(\alpha) = f^{\prime}(0) = 0$, right?

Comment: yea, that's right

Comment: then $ c = 0 $ and $3a\beta^{2} + 2b\beta = 0$ and $3a\alpha^{2} + 2b\alpha= 0$ and $\delta = -(a\alpha^{3} + b\alpha^{2} )$

Comment: When you said that $f'(\beta)=f'(\alpha)=f'(0)=0$, you shouldn't use this to get that c=0, as the function at 0 doesn't have the same form as your polynomial, at 0 your function is $f(x)=1$. You would get two equations from this but can't easily discern that c=0

Comment: It seems you're getting a bit stuck on the solving simultaneous equations bit of your problem. There's no need to use a polynomial as the go between between 1 and 0 on your graph. You could just as easily use a different function such as sin or cos which have two points with differential 0. Then just scale and translate to fit your requirements.

Comment: But how to use an expression to plot such a figure? see https://www.geogebra.org/calculator

Comment: Well you know that you want it to go from 1 to 0 so it needs to have half the magnitude of the usual sine function which goes from 1 to -1, then you want to move it to alpha so use the translation going from $t=0 $ to $t=\alpha $ with $sin(t-\alpha)$ and then you want its midpoint to be halfway between 0 and 1 so add $+0.5$, also you need it to hit its peak and trough at $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively so you want to multiply the time by $\frac{\pi}{\beta-\alpha}$ and finally multiply by -1 as you want it to go from 1 to 0, not 0 to 1

Comment: $ y = \dfrac{\sin(2\pi(x - 3/2))}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}$? for $\beta = 1/2$ and $\alpha = 3/2$

Comment: All good except you need to translate by the midpoint (i.e. $sin(t-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$) and scale the time inside the bracket, i.e. multiply the time by $ \frac{\pi}{\beta-\alpha}$

Comment: you should end up with $$f(x)=-\frac{{sin}(\frac{\pi(x-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})}{\beta-\alpha})}{2}+0.5$$

Comment: perfect. what was the reason for you to put the $\dfrac{\alpha + \beta}{2}$ inside the sin argument?

Comment: You have to place the thing correctly in horizontal direction. sin is symmetric about zero. interval $(\alpha, \beta)$ is symmetric about $\alpha+\beta\over 2$. Replacing $x$ by $x-c$ moves the thing right by $c$ so it is a logical action. (But still there is  need to adjust vertically.)

Answer (score 1):

As your goal is geogebra, this is a solution or https://www.geogebra.org/classic
and also [the other](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator) :

```
a=Curve(t^(3) (b,1)+3 t^(2) (1-t) (b+((c-b)/(2)),1)+3 t^(1) (1-t)^(2) (b+1*((c-b)/(2)),0)+(1-t)^(3) (c,0),t,0,1)
```

[image]

Inspired by [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554029/geogebra-4th-order-bezier-curve). (Alternatively, you can try to use
[build-in `Spline`](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Spline_Command)
function, but math would be even more difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

Your first option was to define  $f$ by
$()=^3+^2++d$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$.
To avoid misunderstanding
let us write
$g()=^3+^2++d$. Then
$g'()=3^2+2+$.

The original function from the picture has
$f(\beta)=1$,
$f(\alpha)=0$,
$f'(\alpha)=0=f'(\beta)$,
so we need to find a b c d so that
$g(\beta)=1$,
$g(\alpha)=0$,
$g'(\alpha)=0=g'(\beta)$.

Than in turn means
$$
  \beta^3+ \beta^2+ \beta +d=1, \tag 1$$
plus similar equations in place of
$g(\alpha)=0$,
$g'(\alpha)=0=g'(\beta)$.
What are the later equations?

After solving the equations you have $a=...$ $b=...$ $c=...$ $d=...$.
You can verify that after substituting that into (1),...
the equations are true.